# Load pytorch model from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, pytorch, torch

I want to load a pytorch model (`model.pt`) from a S3 bucket. I wrote the following code:

```
from smart_open import open as smart_open
import io

load_path = "s3://serial-no-images/yolo-models/model4/model.pt"
with smart_open(load_path) as f:
    buffer = io.BytesIO(f.read())
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(buffer))
```

This results in the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 64: invalid start byte
```

One solution would be to download the model locally, but I want to avoid this and load the model directly from S3. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good solution for that online. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 8):

According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html), the following works:

```
from smart_open import open as smart_open
import io

load_path = "s3://serial-no-images/yolo-models/model4/model.pt"
with smart_open(load_path, 'rb') as f:
    buffer = io.BytesIO(f.read())
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(buffer))
```

I have tried this before, but didn't see that I have to set 'rb' as argument.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  The documentation states that the variable f is "a file-like object (has to implement read(), readline(), tell(), and seek()), OR a string OR os.PathLike object containing a file name".

Comment: can I just do `reloaded_model = torch.load(buffer)`?

Comment: @panc
It depends on how the model was saved.

1. spadel's  approach: Saved the model via `state_dict`.
2. Your approach should be to save the entire model.  

Have a look at the two approaches in https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/saving_and_loading_models_for_inference.html